# Why does Megyn think speaking out shows weakness?

Tags: plot-explanation, bombshell

In *Bombshell* (2019), Fox News anchor Megyn admits to Gil in a closed room about
sexual harassment from Fox News CEO Roger Ailes:

> Megyn: I mean, going on the record...Jesus. **It's basically
> admitting you're the weak one in the herd**.
>
> Gil: No, it's admitting you're the hot one.

Megyn hesitates to go on the record as she believes it
would show her as weak.

Why does Megyn think speaking out shows weakness?

Comment: It's not about her weakness, it's saying that you are asking to open yourself up as a target for being attacked.

Comment: A while since I've seen it but possibly she's afraid that she's admitting she is unable to hack the demands of being a female news anchor in that culture and that now she's being a bit of a cry-baby about it. i.e. she feels that she should be able to take it on the chin and understand that this is just part of what needs to be done to make it in such a ruthlessly competitive job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty well-known that predators in the wild attack the weakest and most vulnerable members of prey groups. For example, this random article on a study I found while looking for evidence for that claim opens with:

> Nature documentaries will tell you that lions, cheetahs, wolves and
> other top predators target the weakest or slowest animals[...] This
> idea has been widely accepted by biologists for many years and was
> formalized in 2003 as the healthy herds hypothesis.

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2023/04/230426104006.htm

She thinks of her own situation using that same paradigm (she literally says it!). Ailes was a "predator" and she was "prey". Because "predators" target the weak, her being victimized means that out of all the possible victims he could have chosen, she was the weakest one. Going public would, in her mind, reveal this "fact" to the world.

Believing that a failing or flaw in oneself caused a bad situation is not an uncommon response to various sorts of trauma:

> Self-blame is a cognitive process in which an individual attributes the occurrence of a stressful event to oneself.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-blame_(psychology)